# Android Webview - Access html elements from Java

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview

I want to know if there is any way to access HTML elements in webview in Android (from Java) without using JavaScript interface? I know JavaScript Interface can be used to pass data but is there any way to directly access HTML elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> there any way to directly access HTML elements?

No, sorry.

Comment: can you provide any source for this?

Comment: @user8295243: There is no API for it [on `WebView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView) or any of its related classes.